# VS2008 link inside Docker occasionally locks up

Tags: docker

Docker version 4.17.1 (101757) on Windows 10 Enterprise [Version 10.0.19045.3086]

I have a Docker image based on symbols/vs2008-vs2010 [50dd89ac1c47], from
https://github.com/symbols-worldwide/docker-vs2008-vs2010

When I build a VS2008 solution inside this Docker image, the container locks during the link stage.
This occurs about one in four builds of the same solution, the other times the build succeeds.

When the container locks up, I can't exec into the container. It takes approx four minutes to timeout.

C:\Users[redacted]>docker container exec -it stoic_ramanujan cmd.exe

```
failed to resize tty, using default size
                                        container [id redacted] encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: context deadline exceeded
```

C:\Users[redacted]>

Is there any way to diagnose why the container is locking up, and how to prevent it?